# Eris sending a message to a specific channel

Tags: javascript, eris

I use Eris to write a bot for Discord.
The documentation says that to send a message to the channel, you need to enter its ID, and then the message being sent,
`createMessage(channelID, content, file)`
but after applying the command, an error is issued: `Invalid file object`

My code looks like this:

```
export default {
    name: 'test',
    description: 'Pi pi poo poo',
    execute: async (i) => {
        await
        i.createMessage('535986994145263663', 'Yo');
    },
};
```

Maybe I missed something?

I wrote the variables in different order, but nothing happened

Comment: It doesn't seem like discord.js so removed that tag. Any reason you're using this instead of the well-documented discord.js package though? What is `i`? An `interaction`? Where do you call `execute`?

Answer (score 0):

you have placed the wrong params.

```
export default {
    name: 'test',
    description: 'Pi pi poo poo',
    execute: async (i) => {
        await i.createMessage('Yo');
    },
};
```

it seems like you have assumed that [interaction.createMessage](https://abal.moe/Eris/docs/0.17.1/CommandInteraction#method-createMessage) takes the exact same params as [client.createMessage](https://abal.moe/Eris/docs/0.17.1/Client#method-createMessage) which is not true.
**happy coding ;)**